# Re-Direct with document.url.match 

Tags: javascript, url, dom, string-matching

My goal is to redirect my website to (/2012/index.php)

ONLY IF the user goes to ( http://www.neonblackmag.com )

ELSE IF

the user goes to ( http://neonblackmag.com.s73231.gridserver.com ) they will not be re-directed... ( this way i can still work on my website and view it from this url ( the temp url )

I have tried the following script and  variations, i have been unsuccessful in getting this to work thus far....

```
<script language="javascript">
if (document.URL.match("http://www.neonblackmag.com/")); {
location.replace("http://www.neonblackmag.com/2012"); }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(location.href.match(/www.neonblackmag.com/)){
        location.replace("http://www.neonblackmag.com/2012");
    }
</script>
```

You should use regular expression as an argument of match (if you're not using https you can drop match for http://...

In your solution the semicolon after `if` should be removed - and I think that's it, mine is using `location.href` instead of `document.URL`.

You can also match subfolders using `location.href.match(/www.neonblackmag.com\/subfolder/)` etc

Cheers

G.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! - I tried your code  with an alert and it is not throwing the alert.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    if(location.href.match(/www.neonblackmag.com/)){
alert("This site is still under development, you are currently viewing a testing version of this website, if you feel you have gotten this message by mistake, please contact Neon Black Magazine at info@neonblackmag.com");}</script>

Comment: I've just checked on my domain and I'm getting the alert message in FF 8.0 and IE 8.0, you can try to escape dots in the domain by changing /www.neonblackmag.com/ to /www\.neonblackmag\.com/ --- UPDATE: your domain is set to neonblackmag.com not www.neonblackmag.com so it that's a webconfig which is redirecting www to non-www the match won't work, I see the alert now btw :)

Answer (score 1):

`document.url` doesn't appear to be settable, afaict. You probably want `window.location`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.location.hostname === "www.neonblackmag.com") {
    window.location.pathname = '/2012';
}
</script>
```

(Don't use `language="javascript"`. It's deprecated.)

Comment: This code is correct and a nicer solution than "match". But the main issue in the original was the `;` after the `if` statement, which results in it getting treated as an empty statement, and `location.replace` always getting called regardless of the condition.

Comment: I tried this and i am still getting the same result when i goto : http://neonblackmag.com.s73231.gridserver.com ...

Answer (score 0):

Anyone at any time can disable JavaScript and continue viewing your site.  There are better ways to do this, mostly on the server side.

To directly answer your questions, this code will do what you want.  Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MjZWh/) for it.

```
var the_url = window.location.href;
document.write(the_url);

// This is our pretend URL
// Remove this next line in production
var the_url = 'http://www.neonblackmag.com/';

if (the_url.indexOf('http://www.neonblackmag.com/') !== -1)
    window.location.href = 'http://www.neonblackmag.com/2012/index.php';
else
    alert('Welcome');
```

As I said, this can be easily bypassed.  It'd be enough to stop a person who can check email and do basic Google searches.

---

On the server side is where you really have power.  In your PHP code you can limit requests to only coming from your IP, or only any other variable factor, and no one can get in.  If you don't like the request, send them somewhere else instead of giving them the page.

```
header('Location: /2012/index.php'); // PHP code for a redirect
```

There are plenty of other ways to do it, but this is one of the simpler.  Others include, redirecting the entire domain, or creating a test sub domain and only allow requests to that.

Comment: while i feel like this is the correct approach for javascript, it is still redirecting when i goto :  http://neonblackmag.com.s73231.gridserver.com : - which is just the temporary url for my server http://neonblackmag.com ... maybe i just cant do what i am wanting to do....